# How to create a array using json value

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have a json record like blow

```
[{"low":null,"high":10,"type":2,"value":0},{"low":10,"high":60,"type":1,"value":10},{"low":60,"high":null,"type":2,"value":11}]
```

I would like to create array using this. i tried json_decode its not help i just want create a associative array from this json

any help
thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure you're passing `true` to the second parameter in [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/json_decode), which specifies that you want an associative array returned.

```
$arr = json_decode($string, true);
```

> **Parameters**
>    *assoc*
>     When `TRUE`, returned objects will be converted into associative arrays.

Answer (score 1):

see this page : http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

use json_decode with this format : json_decode($value,true);

your code : http://pastebin.com/4vdVHjQN